# Add div to table after each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this table: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjvwOx
Each time I click a row (e.g 1st row 'NODE ID 1'), the div with the id `#divTemplate` should appear below the row as you can see in the demo link.

**The problems are** (I know of) :

1. The div displays all the contents from endpointsData object(e.g if I click on the first row,
   the div should contain 'EPID: 1', not 'EPID: 1234' as you can see in demo).
2. The 'accordion' display of the div works chaotic. In demo you can see if you press
   multiple times on a row, the div just appears in different places, till it doesn't work any more

For the 1st problem I did this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Owvbae (I selected each id from div)

```
$("#epid").text(roomValue[key[0]]);
$("#clslist").text(roomValue[key[1]]);
$("#type").text(roomValue[key[2]]);
$("#zplus").text(roomValue[key[3]]);
```

Is there a way I can loop this?
Any ideas for the second problem?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the 'accordion' you should put it in your `<tr class="header">`, then use jquery and listen when pressed on it.

```
$('.header').on('click' function() {
// code
});
```

After that use `$('this')` to get what has been pressed, and target it's children row `.children([selector])` to manipulate the acordion.